# Python geodesic equation differential function not working

Tags: python, math, sympy, physics

```
from sympy import *

M,G,c,t,τ,r,θ,ϕ = symbols(" M G c t τ r θ ϕ")

coor = [t,r,θ,ϕ,τ]
rs = 2*G*M/(c**2)

MM = diag(2*G*M/(c**2*r) - 1,
 1/(-2*G*M/(c**2*r) + 1),
 r**2,
 r**2*sin(θ)**2)

MI = MM.inv(method="LU")

def m(i,j):
    return MM[i, j]

def dm(i,j,k):
    return diff(m(i,j),coor[k])

def im(i,j):
    return MI[i,j]

def gamma(i,j,k):
    s = 0 
    for l in range(4):
        s += 0.5*im(i,l)*(dm(l,j,k)+dm(l,k,j)-dm(j,k,l))
    return simplify(s)

def da(i,c):
    return diff(m(i),coor[c])

def db(j,c):
    return diff(m(j),coor[c])

def geodesic(i,j,k,c):
    geo = gamma(i,j,k)*da(i,c)*db(i,c)
    return geo

print(geodesic(1,0,0,5))
```

I am trying to make it so when I plug these values into the geodesic equation it will give me an answer but the problem is there are two derivatives with variables i,j with respect to τ but I can't seem to define those properly so that I may multiply them to get the geodesic equation. Can anyone please help. Thank you.

Comment: You know that there are much better ways to write down and integrate the geodesic equations of a particle in Schwazschild gravity. For starter, due to spherical symmetry of the metric, you have conservation of angular momentum, which readily reduces your problem from 3+1 dimensions to 2+1, so you need to calculate fewer of these Cristoffel symbols. Plus, taking the Largangian approach and deriving the equations as Euler-Lagrange equations, things are easier to simplify and spot the conservation laws induced from the rotational invariance of the metric.

Answer (score 0):

In your call to `geodesic` you pass an integer for `c` but then in `geodesic` you pass `coor[c]` to `da` and `db` but they are expecting integers -- and 0 based integers -- so in geodesic pass `c - 1` to `da` and `db`.

In `geodesic` you pass `i` to `da` and `db` -- should one of those be `j`?

In `da` and `db` you call `m` with a single argument. What do you mean my that?

Comment: da and db are supposed to be the last two derivatives

Comment: `m` takes to arguments to give the element of MM.   What should m(i) return?